# Equivalent idiom for a Romanian expression regarding status

Tags: idioms

I am looking for an English equivalent of the Romanian saying "Se întâmplă și la case mai mari" (literally: it also happens in larger houses). It suggests that bad things not only happen to poor people but also the richer have their (similar) problems.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Proverbs 13:8 (Contemporary English Version) [[Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/proverbs/13-8.htm)] reads:
_The rich may have to pay a ransom, but the poor don't have that problem._ Not exactly what you want, and not really in common use.

Comment: “Queens have their problems too”